# on PubSubHubbub subscription of Wordpress blogs

Tags: wordpress, webhooks, websub

I'm setting up a PubSubHubbub subscription on a Wordpress blog using the tutorial [here](https://en.support.wordpress.com/pubsubhubbub/), which states that the information about the hub is included in the feed "using an `atom:link` tag with a `rel='hub'` attribute". However, the blog I want to subscribe to [(link here)](https://blog.kraken.com/feed/) does not have the `rel='hub'` attribute. Does it mean there is no way to get PuSH notification about it please? Could I set up a hub myself and link it to the atom address? Thanks.